# Change the apex:commandButton value from 'Return to Uploader' to 'Done' from Javascript (Jquery)

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller, jquery

I have a requirement to change the `value` of `apex:commandButton` from **'return to uploader'** to **'Done'** using Javascript(Jquery).

**Below is my VF Page code:**

```
<apex:commandButton style="float: right;" id="buttonId" value="Return to uploader" action="{!goToTypeSelection}" rendered="{!showAutoMatchUpload}" />
```

**Below is my Javascript code that I am trying to change:**

```
$upload = $(".upload[data-status='pending']").filter(":first"); //There is a HTML tag with data-status='Pending' in my HTML component that I have not shown.
if($upload.length == 0){
   $('#buttonId').attr('value', 'Done');
   console.log($("[id$=buttonId]").val());
}
```

Though I changed the attribute value to done from Javascript as shown above, the button is not getting changed.

I possibly see I am doing something wrong but not sure what is going wrong:

1. I am changing the attribute value the wrong way. If yes, can you please suggest on how to change the value of the apex:commandbutton from JS.
2. I have to rerender the button again after changing the attribute value from Javascript. If yes, can you please let me know on how to rerender the button from the Javascript.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way, instead of in the VF Page itself (and if you used custom labels the admin could override the text through the setup UI) and how are you getting the button ID? With the latter, the ID in the page is generated based on the page structure and isn't just the value specified in the VF Page itself.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to answer these extra points.

Comment: @PhilW, I am doing this way because the whole code is already built in Javascript. So I had to continue with JS. Also, regarding the ID, I was able to console.log and the data is getting displayed properly. Hence, the code with the Id is working fine

Comment: sorry, if I have understood your question wrong. Is there any other way of the changing the button value using JavaScript (it's fine if it is through any other approach)

Comment: This is a visual force page, with an apex command button. Just update the VF Page to change the label. What you appear to be doing is a hack.

Comment: No, @PhilW. I wanted to change the apex:command button value dynamically whenever $upload.length == 0. How do I do that dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `<button>` that's generated here does have a `value` property, but that's actually just the value submitted to the server, and not the actual label of the button. The `value` is actually just the `innerHTML`/`innerText` of the button, so you need to use `.html()` or `.text()` to set the value:

```
$("[data-submit-button]").text("Done");
```

Second, Visualforce does some kind of transformation on the `id` property for `<apex:*>` elements, which ends up looking like `j_id0:j_id1:buttonId`; the exact format will depend on the page, if any parent elements have `id` values, and whether or not the button is in an `<apex:pageBlockButtons>` element, which will cause two buttons to appear with slightly different ID values, such as `idForm:idPageBlock:idPageBlockButtons:buttonId` and `idForm:idPageBlock:idPageBlockButtons:bottom:buttonId`.

Use either a `data-` property or a CSS `class` to target the button, or use the `$Component` variable to get the correct Id.

Examples:

```
$("#{!$Component.idForm.idPageBlock.idPageBlockButtons.buttonId}")
```

Or:

```
$("[data-submit-button]")
```

Where the button is changed to:

```
<apex:commandButton html-data-submit-button="submit" ...
```

Or:

```
$(".submitButton")
```

And setting a style class:

```
<apex:commandButton styleClass="submitButton" ...
```